# Methods of SDE calibration

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

There is somewhere summary of methods that can be used to estimate parameters of SDE?

I currently using MLE and regression due to linear dependence between samples. I searching for something different due to many problems with maintainability of this SDE when using calibration method like this.

I think it should be exist some method that works similar to downhill-simplex algorithm, since I want avoid hassle with math, but I can't find any.

Comment: question was answered on http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/22471/methods-of-sde-calibration